# Coroutine never calls API after job either cancelled or pending

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How do I make calls when I click loan1 button happen after getting a JobCancellationException on other calls ?

```
class MainRepository{

   //called many times
   suspend fun getLoanOptions(): Resource<LoanOptionsResponse> {
        return try {
            val response = apiService.getLoanOptions("id")
            responseHandler.handleSuccess(response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            responseHandler.handleException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        Timber.e("$throwable")
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob() + exceptionHandler

    private val mainRepo: MainRepository by lazy { MainRepository() }

    //extra calls to this fails 
    fun getLoanOptions(): LiveData<Resource<LoanOptionsResponse>> {
        return liveData(coroutineContext) {
            val data = mainRepo.getLoanOptions()
            emit(Resource.loading(null))
            emit(data)

        }
    }

   override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }

}
```

```
 //in mainactivity I call it

 class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

 val vm: MainViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)  }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      loan1.setOnClickListener {
         // if any previous api has 403 this one does not work any more ?
         vm.getLoanOptions().observe(this, Observer {
           //data
         }
      }

      loan2.setOnClickListener {

      }

    }
 }
```

I clicked on button -> Api is called -> got success response

Again I clicked on -> Api is called -> got success response

I get 403 in other API call

I clicked on button -> Api is not called

No other Api calls gets called in this Activity :(

I get this after few minutes

```
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: 403 means "Forbidden". It is about your web service that has banned you and do not response to your requests.

Comment: Any solution please ?

Comment: @user2021346 you could paste your implementation here too. but so far I have not been able to catch JobCancellationException and pass it upstream. Since its not exclusively thrown at runtime. It's weird consequent coroutines get cancelled even with ' SupervisorJob() '